# Is it possible to define `case` clauses with an elixir macro?

Tags: macros, elixir

I'd like to define a subset of the cases in my `case` clause with a macro. Unfortunately, I'm getting a syntax error. Here's what I have:

```elixir
defmodule Yacht do
  @type category ::
          :ones
          | :twos
          | :threes
          | :fours
          | :fives
          | :sixes

  defmacro count_case(dice, symbol, value) do
    quote do
      unquote(symbol) ->
        unquote(value) * Enum.count(unquote(dice), &(&1 == unquote(value)))
    end
  end

  @doc """
  Calculate the score of 5 dice using the given category's scoring method.
  """
  @spec score(category :: category(), dice :: [integer]) :: integer
  def score(category, dice) do
    case category do
      # these cause syntax errors if uncommented
      # count_case(dice, :ones, 1)
      # count_case(dice, :twos, 2)

      # these work as expected
      :threes ->
        3 * Enum.count(dice, &(&1 == 3))

      :fours ->
        4 * Enum.count(dice, &(&1 == 4))

      :fives ->
        5 * Enum.count(dice, &(&1 == 5))

      :sixes ->
        6 * Enum.count(dice, &(&1 == 6))
    end
  end
end
```

This gives the error at `:threes`:

```
** (SyntaxError) lib/yacht.ex:32: unexpected operator ->. If you want to define multiple clauses, the first expression must use ->. Syntax error before: '->'
    (elixir 1.15.5) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:377: anonymous fn/5 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_workers/8
```

I found [this forum thread](https://elixirforum.com/t/using-a-macro-to-generate-case-statements/3650) about defining cases with macros, but it recommends defining the entire case as syntax blocks and there are some extra cases not shown here that I don't want to do that with.

So. Is there a way to define a single `case` item with a macro?

Comment: For what I know about macros, I think that you cannot inject part of expression in the case, the macro is not just a code generator they need to be in a context in which they are valid. You could define a macro for the entire `case` expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** Technically, it’s possible, but in a way, you won’t like let alone use it.

---

Let’s start with distilling the issue. This is the [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code.

```elixir
defmodule Yacht do
  defmacro count(symbol, value) do
    quote do
      unquote(symbol) -> unquote(value)
    end
  end

  def score(category) do
    case category do
      # this causes `unexpected operator ->`
      count(:one, 1)

      # this works as expected
      :two -> 2
    end
  end
end
```

What happens when we have generic inline clauses? Let’s see.

```elixir
quote do
  case category do
    :one -> 1
    :two -> 2
  end
end
#⇒ {:case, [],
#  [
#    {:category, [], Elixir},
#    [do: [{:->, [], [[:one], 1]}, {:->, [], [[:two], 2]}]]
#  ]}
```

As one might see, `case` clauses are stacked into a list under `do` block in the AST. Unfortunately, there is no `unquote` variant allowing us to embed our elements into the list, separated with *spaces* in code. The chicken-egg-like issue is appearing here, for our code to be understandable by a parser, we want to inject AST into something that was not yet compiled to AST.

The best resort would be to compile the rest of the clauses into AST and inject our AST into it. Somewhat alongside the below would work

```elixir
defmodule Yacht do
  defmodule Counter do
    def count(symbol, value) do
      quote do
        unquote(symbol) -> unquote(value)
      end
    end
    def counts(symbol_values) do
      for [symbol, value] <- symbol_values, do: hd(count(symbol, value))
    end
  end

  def score(category) do
    case category do
      [unquote_splicing(
        Counter.counts([[:one, 1]]) ++ 
        quote do: (:two -> 2))]
    end
  end
end
```

Resulting in:

```elixir
iex||2 ▶ Yacht.score(:one)
1
iex||3 ▶ Yacht.score(:two)
2
```

As stated above, this is not something one wants to use in the real project and I put the answer only to dive it all turtles down.

---

*Sidenote:* another module is needed to make `Yacht.Counter.counts/1` available *during* compilation of `Yacht`.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the explanation! I wasn't thinking of the `:sym -> exp` as part of a larger expression, so it didn't occur to me that it couldn't be (easily) generated on its own. I (incorrectly) assumed that a macro could generate valid code of any size, but it seems that's not the case.

Comment: @xavdid macro surely can generate a valid code of any size; the issue here is the resulting AST is to be **injected** into something bigger. `quote do: (:foo -> bar)` obviously works and it’s even used in the working snippet above.

Comment: If you have no _trailing_ `foo -> bar` clauses, simple `unquote_splicing/1` above would perfectly do what you want it to do out of the box.